# Accessing SharePoint's SQL Server via an external HTTP Request

Tags: sharepoint, httprequest

I want to access my SharePoint's SQL Database using an external web application running on localhost. It will just send 2 parameters to my SharePoint application and it will create a new row in the database, that's all. Is this possible?

Comment: You should never access SharePoint DBs Directly. What exactly you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Exactly what it says: to access the SharePoint DB from outside of the SharePoint enterprise portal.

Is it possible to access the database indirectly then? I'll send a HTTP request to a web service exposed in the portal, and the web service will trigger an insert into the SQL database.